# 2 Submit buttons on ASP page

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP page with a form.  It has a selection box, a test field with an add button to add whatever text is typed into the selection box.  I then have a file upload box with a button. And then finally, I have a submit button.

What I want to do with the file upload and button (called import) is to point to a file and then click the import button to read a text file, copy the contents and put it in the selection box.

I think I may have just answered my own question now by writing it out.  I probably have to launch some server side script that uploads the file and feeds back the info to the web page.

What I need help with is if I can update a ASP variable on the button click Import I should then be able to do everything I want.  Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am able to get what you are asking, then

I think you know that you will have to read the content of file, but in order to show the same in textbox or textarea, you need some event which will bind the textbox again with the content of the file.

May be you can trigger postback after the upload button click, how to do that?

1) By making a dummy button and calling its event

2) By adding text of file to javascript variable from code behind.

3) By making a sample Import button self (instead of file upload etc)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Iti Tyagi.  I found a solution.  I simply had a hidden text field.  When a specific button is clicked, I changed the text in the hidden field and when the form was submitted, I read the text and based on the text, my webpage would do the appropriate thing I wanted.